# OO:Doc -perl module for Openoffic

Tags: perl, openoffice.org, cpan

I want to automate some writer tasks. I need to create a `.odt` writer
document with `oo:doc` using methods such as create paragraph and append
paragraph. The problem is that append paragraph and create paragraph does not
allow text to start at middle of page or at a certain column, ie

```
Name             Surname              Address
```

When I unzip the "master" document I want to  to create, when I inspect the content.xml file i see the xml equivalent is

```
" <text:p text:style-name="Text_20_body"><text:s text:c="115"/><text:span text:style-name="T1"><text:s/>Hallo how are you today</text:span></text:p><text:p text:style-name="P1"><text:s text:c="116"/>I hope you are well also</text:p><text:p text:style-name="P1""
```

How do I set the `text:c` and `text:s` element(s) from within `oo::doc`

**Question2:**

How do i set the formatting of a paragraph
to only extend from ie column 20 to column 80

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those  elements are for runs of non-breaking spaces.  the text:c attribute says how many spaces there are.

That doesn't strike me as a solution to what you want, which is to change the margins and position of a paragraph, yes?

Do you have a document that you want to use as a template, where the text will be inserted?  Or ar you trying to create the entire page from scratch?

I think you want to use OpenOffice.org to create a Writer document that has the structure you want, then look at the XML to see what the markup is that accomplishes that.  Look at paragraph-level styles or even frames if that is what is used.  You might be able to create insertion points for your generated content by then adding magic-text phrases that you can scan for.

Then figure out how to get that done with the perl module.